# How to store a table of string list in azure

Tags: azure

I have a list of string values like a dictionary, and I have to run string search on the values but I couldn't decide where to put this list and how to store it.

First, I consider storing them inside a table storage (because it is cheap and  run queries on PK/RK fast) but since I cannot categorize or group the list I won't be utilizing table storage fully (PK and RK indexing)

I am using documentDB as my main data storage, I can store the list inside a document but since the list can easily grow to the limits of document, I have to implement a splitting algorithm like storing the chunks of 1000 elements in one document and then I have to query among these multiple documents when i searching.

Formerly i had stored them inside a mssql table and all was good until we had some growth concerns.

The row i am trying to store just have the word itself(string) and use counter(int).

Edit: Data example and usage

```
Label       UsageCount
---------   ---------- 
Lorem        13 
Lorem ipsum  22 
dolor        909 
sit          12 
Amet         456 
consectetur  66 
ameiscing   387 
elit         5 
...
```

Usage: I query the labels while user is writing to suggest him results via a starts with query, 
like user writes 'ame', i should show him 'Amet' and 'ameiscing', thats a simple case insensitive search query.

Comment: Can you describe how you would query this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make two suggestions. Please see if any of these work out for you:

1. **Using Search Service**: Azure Search Service recently came out with a new functionality called [`suggestions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798936.aspx). Typically it is used in search boxes to provide type-ahead suggestions as users are entering search terms.
2. **Using Azure Table Service**: If you use Table Service, here's one thing you could do to implement this kind of functionality. Essentially it would require you to duplicate the data many times over. Taking your example, this is how the data would look like in your search table:

[image]

As the user start typing the word, you do query on the letters entered so far e.g. user types `a`, your query will be `PartitionKey eq 'a'`, then as the user types `am`, your query would be `PartitionKey eq 'am'` and so on. The query will scan the partitions accordingly and return you words that start with the letters typed by the user so far.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I wouldn't think using table service like that. Is this practical or you are suggesting that because I wanted to use table service?

Comment: Primarily because you wanted to use table service. I haven't tried this approach personally.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, we concluded on using Azure search service since it provides better results and easier to implement, at least for now.